# How to switch between desktop enviroments in Win-Kex?

Tags: linux, windows, kali-linux

Currently I am running wsl2 on my windows computer and using the win-kex application to get a GUI version of Kali Linux. I have followed the steps listed here https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/switching-desktop-environments/ and here https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-kde-dekstop-on-kali-linux but I am unable to switch to KDE (I cannot do Step 4). Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation tells us to press F8.

Session Management @ https://www.kali.org/docs/wsl/win-kex-win/

> Pressing “F8” will open the client’s context menu, which allows to
> manage the client sessions, e.g. close the client, switch between full
> screen and window, etc.) You can disconnect from active sessions by
> pressing “F8” -> “Exit viewer”, this will close the client but leave
> the session running in the background You can re-connect to a session
> by typing kex --win --start-client